# How can I counter Shotguns?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive*, shotguns impose a danger (when somebody is using it against you). They can easily 1-hit-KO you if used correctly.

Is there a method that I can use to prevent shotgun-wielding opponents from completely obliterating me? And if so, what is that method?

Comment: Shoot them in the head first.

Comment: Flashbangs. Long range. Shoot first ask questions later...

Comment: @SimonL So there's no effective method I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on my earlier comment, the most effective way of killing someone using a shotgun is to kill them at long range. Shotguns are not effective to use at a long range because of their: [large bullet spread and high range-damage fall off](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuOy-5I1VcBMdGZmYndxUjctc1VNUDZHTXJFUE9Dbmc#gid=0) (thanks to @Decency for this link).

That is unfortunately not a likely scenario. Most people who are using a shotgun are going to be using it in a closed environment where they can get up and personal with you as that is where the shotgun is the most effective. Failing that, if they *have* to engage a target at long range they will likely resort to using their pistol instead.

If they are camping an objective and you are in a closed environment you will have to resort to using flashbangs ([[CS:GO Pro Tips] Curse adreN - Using Flashbangs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjTp87V5ip4) great video for learning how to effectively use flashbangs) or simply pulling the trigger first and hope you get a headshot for a quick kill.